# React Router V4 - Uncaught TypeError: location.search.charAt is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Since React Router change from "query" to "search".
I use the following code to query from search

Query function:

```
  setFilter(query) {
        this.props.history.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname, search: query });
  }
```

Search Parameter:

```
 applyFilter() {
    const newFilter = {};
    if (this.state.content) {
        newFilter.content = this.state.content;
    }
    if (this.state.fromDate) {
        newFilter.fromDate = this.state.fromDate;
    }
    if (this.state.toDate) {
        newFilter.toDate = this.state.toDate;
        }
    this.props.setFilter(newFilter);
  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: location.search.charAt is not a function
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: why are you passing a custom object to history.push i.e., search:query?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar query is an object that he is passing to search, under applyFilter function he is creating an object and passing that too setFilter function as query

Comment: @Think-Twice, that's correct, I just don't know how to use history.push() since I learn from the react-router v2.

Comment: To fix the issue remove search  and keep it like this this.props.history.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname}); and use query object where it's needed

Comment: @Think-Twice, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments. You need to remove query object to fix the issue

```
setFilter(query) {
    this.props.history.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname});
    //use query object here or wherever required
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass a string to search property as explained on [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/location), not an object

Answer (score 2):

Something else that worked for me is this:

```
  setFilter(query) {
        const searchParamsObject = new URLSearchParams(query);
        this.props.history.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname, search: searchParamsObject.toString() });
  }
```